# Possibly Soft-Bricked Droid Razr M

Tags: unbricking, motorola-droid-razr

I'm currently in possession of a Droid Razr M that may be "soft-bricked". It's bootscreen won't progress beyond the red Motorola logo. I can't turn it off unless I do it via soft rebooting, in which case it just reboots and gets stuck at the logo again. I've already done a hard (factory) reset, which I assume succeeded. The device never had its bootloader unlocked, nor was it rooted. It did receive all available OS updates available for it (it only went up to some version of KitKat). This is also not a developer edition.

At this point, what I want to know is: can the device have its bootloader unlocked or be rooted in any way? If not, is there anything I can do to restore this device to some kind of working order? I'm unsure as to where I would get appropriate stock images for the device (it had a Verizon-customized Android installed on it), so I was planning on flashing something like LineageOS. If there is nothing I can do for the device at this point, I'd like to know so I can avoid wasting time on it. Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Comment: I downloaded `adb` and `fastboot`, and neither of those can even see my phone when attached via usb (I'm using Ubuntu Gnome as my host system). I'm beginning to think this device is completely hosed at this point.

Comment: you've probably moved on, but you should at least be able to factory reset. there will be two button combinations, one to get into the fastboot loader, and one to get into recovery mode from there. from recovery mode you can do a factory reset. there will also be a button combo for safe mode which you should try before factory reset. the button combos vary for every device.

Comment: I tried to boot into safe mode using the button combos for my device, but that didn't work. I think I was able to access the fastboot menu and I selected "factory reset", but that seems to be ineffective as well; the device still gets stuck on the Motorola logo. Thank you for your help anyway.